websocket stuck at co_await when using it at the child coroutine of one coroutine
I tried to use one ws object in two coroutines, one coroutine for sending and another for receiving. However, when I tried to use a child coroutine in the existing coroutine, the code stuck at the co_await's async_write (in the 'while' part). Are there anything wrong when I call the child coroutine?
the async_write func worked in the father coroutine with while(1), but in the child coroutine it can only work 1 time and stuck at next time.
Here is my client code.
//
// Copyright (c) 2022 Klemens D. Morgenstern (klemens dot morgenstern at gmx dot net)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
// Official repository: https://github.com/boostorg/beast
//

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Example: WebSocket client, coroutine
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_awaitable.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#if defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT)

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
net::awaitable<void> do_write_loop(auto& ws, std::string text) {
    std::cout << "before while";
        //std::cout << "do_write_loop"<<i<<std::endl;
        co_await ws.async_write(net::buffer(std::string(text)));
}

net::awaitable<void> do_read_loop(auto& ws) {
    beast::flat_buffer buffer;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "do_read_loop";
        co_await ws.async_read(buffer);
        std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer.data()) << std::endl;
    }
}

net::awaitable<void> do_session(
    std::string host,
    std::string port,
    std::string text)
{
    auto resolver = net::use_awaitable.as_default_on(
        tcp::resolver(co_await net::this_coro::executor));
    auto ws = net::use_awaitable.as_default_on(
        websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream>(co_await net::this_coro::executor));
    auto const results = co_await resolver.async_resolve(host, port);
    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
    auto ep = co_await beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).async_connect(results);
    host += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());
    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).expires_never();
    ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(beast::role_type::client));
    ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
        [](websocket::request_type& req)
        {
            req.set(http::field::user_agent,
            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
            " websocket-client-coro");
        }));
    co_await ws.async_handshake(host, "/");
    std::cout << "after handshake";
    //while (1) {
    //    co_await ws.async_write(net::buffer(std::string(text)));
    //}






    net::io_context ioc2;
    auto executor = co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor;
    // Start the write and read loops concurrently
        net::co_spawn(ioc2,
            do_write_loop(ws, text), [](std::exception_ptr e)
            {
                if (e)
                    try
                {
                    std::cout << "enter e";
                    std::rethrow_exception(e);
                }
                catch (std::exception& e)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
                }
            });
    net::co_spawn(ioc2,
        do_read_loop(ws), [](std::exception_ptr e)
        {
            if (e)
                try
            {
                std::rethrow_exception(e);
            }
            catch (std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
            }
        });
    ioc2.run();
    //ioc3.run();
    // Wait for both tasks to complete (this will never happen)
    //co_await net::when_all(std::move(write_loop_task), std::move(read_loop_task));

    // Close the WebSocket connection (this will never be reached)
    co_await ws.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Check command line arguments.
    /*if (argc != 4)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: websocket-client-awaitable <host> <port> <text>\n"
                  << "Example:\n"
                  << "    websocket-client-awaitable echo.websocket.org 80 \"Hello, world!\"\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }*/
    //auto const host = argv[1];
    //auto const port = argv[2];
    //auto const text = argv[3];
    auto const host = "127.0.0.1";
    auto const port = "12345";
    auto const text = "argv[3]";

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    net::co_spawn(ioc,
                  do_session(host, port, text),
                  [](std::exception_ptr e)
                  {
                      if (e)
                          try
                          {
                              std::rethrow_exception(e);
                          }
                          catch (std::exception &e)
                          {
                              std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
                          }
                  });

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the socket is closed.
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#else

int main(int, char *[])
{
    std::printf("awaitables require C++20\n");
    return 1;
}

#endif


You are needlessly using a second iocontext, which you then do a blocking wait on:
ioc2.run();

Instead use the coro's executor:
auto ex = co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor;
// Start the write and read loops concurrently
co_spawn(ex, do_write_loop(ws, text), rethrow);
co_spawn(ex, do_read_loop(ws), rethrow);

Or better yet, use awaitable-operators to coordinate the parallel work:
co_await (do_write_loop(ws, text) && do_read_loop(ws));

Note that as given do_write_loop isn't a loop at all, and it will complete.
Live Demo
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace beast     = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http      = beast::http;          // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket;     // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net       = boost::asio;          // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp           = boost::asio::ip::tcp; // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
using Resolver      = net::deferred_t::as_default_on_t<tcp::resolver>;
using WebSock       = net::deferred_t::as_default_on_t<websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream>>;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace net::experimental::awaitable_operators;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
net::awaitable<void> do_write_loop(WebSock& ws, std::string const& text) {
    std::cout << "before while" << std::endl;
    // std::cout << "do_write_loop" << i << std::endl;
    co_await ws.async_write(net::buffer(text));
}

net::awaitable<void> do_read_loop(WebSock& ws) {
    beast::flat_buffer buffer;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "do_read_loop" << std::endl;
        co_await ws.async_read(buffer);
        std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer.data()) << std::endl;
    }
}

net::awaitable<void> do_session(std::string host, std::string port, std::string text) {
    auto    ex = co_await net::this_coro::executor;
    WebSock ws(ex);

    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).expires_after(30s);
    auto ep = co_await beast::get_lowest_layer(ws)                //
                  .async_connect(co_await Resolver(ex)            //
                                     .async_resolve(host, port)); //
    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).expires_never();

    std::cout << "TCP connected to " << ep << std::endl;
    host += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

    {
        using Opts = websocket::stream_base;
        ws.set_option(Opts::timeout::suggested(beast::role_type::client));
        ws.set_option(Opts::decorator(
                    [](websocket::request_type& req) { req.set(http::field::user_agent, "my-client-1.0"); }));
    }
    co_await ws.async_handshake(host, "/");

    std::cout << "after handshake" << std::endl;
    co_await (do_write_loop(ws, text) && do_read_loop(ws));

    // Close the WebSocket connection (this will never be reached)
    co_await ws.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
static inline void rethrow(std::exception_ptr ep) try {
    if (ep)
        std::rethrow_exception(ep);
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << "\n rethrow_exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    auto const host = "127.0.0.1";
    auto const port = "12345";
    auto const text = "hello world";

    net::io_context ioc;
    co_spawn(ioc, do_session(host, port, text), rethrow);

    ioc.run();
}



Thank you for your answer! Using co_await(func) worked, and co_await async_write in func didn't get blocked. But I wonder why co_await async_write in func called by ioc.run() can only run once and then stuck?

Again, because run() blocks. So the main ioc cannot make any progress because it is waiting for ioc2
